# Multiple INSERT queries using PDO & SQLite

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I have this sqlite3 db:

```
CREATE TABLE links (
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
 name TEXT UNIQUE,
 link1 TEXT,
 link2 TEXT,
 link3 TEXT
);
```

And I am trying to insert multiple entries in the same query, this is my code:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:db.sqlite');

$sql = "INSERT INTO links VALUES";

$filelines = file('filename');

foreach($filelines as $key => $line)
{
 if(count($filelines)-1==$key)
  $sql .= "(NULL, '".trim($line)."', '', '', '');";
 else
  $sql .= "(NULL, '".trim($line)."', '', '', ''),";
}

$insert = $db->prepare($sql);

$insert->execute();
```

Single inserts works fine but with this code I get the php error:

**Call to a member function execute() on a non-object**

I've also tried creating the sql query like 'VALUES(...,...), VALUES(...,...),... but get the same error:

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support the `VALUES (...), (...), (...)` syntax (see [the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) ).  So you need to do only one row per `INSERT` query...

The reason for the error itself is that since there's a query error, `PDO::prepare()` [returns false](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php).  You should check it to make sure the `->prepare()` call worked:

```
$insert = $db->prepare($sql);

if (!$insert) {
    die($db->errorInfo());
    // Or you could throw an exception, or otherwise handle the error...
}

$insert->execute();
```

Comment: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html shows that multiple values should be able to be inserted. But when I'm testing it with SQLite3 and php it doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Justin That's because it was added in SQLite 3.7.11 and current releases have an older version: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19340769/736162